# Show that $x \left(\sum\limits_{n\leq x} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}\right) +\theta(x)=O(x)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, estimation

I know that
$$x\left(\sum\limits_{n\leq x} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}\right)+\theta(x) \leq  x\left(\sum\limits_{n\leq x} \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)+\theta(x)=x\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln{x}\right)^2+Cx+O(\ln x)+O(x)$$

where $\theta(x)=\sum\limits_{p\leq x} \ln p$

Is that equal to $O(x(\ln x)^2)$ not $O(x)$?

Comment: To show  $\theta(x) = O(x)$ you can look at ${2n \choose n} \ge \prod_{p \in (n,2n]} p$ and $2^{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n \choose k} \ge {2n \choose n}$

Comment: yes that i know the other term is the problem

Comment: What other term, please correct your question and make things clear

Comment: i want to show $x\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} $+$\theta(x)$=$O(x)$

Comment: not just $\theta(x)$

Comment: $\sum_n \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2}$ converges, its partial sums are bounded.

Comment: Oh so $x\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} $$\leq$$x\sum^{n_0}_{n=1} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} $ for some $n_0\leq x$. Hence, $x\sum_{n\leq x} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} $$\leq Mx$ where M is the bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3101320/sum-n-leq-x-frac-log-nn3-c-frac-log-x2x2-frac-14x2/) question purely for the links to the theoretical material (and to some extent, similarity).

From [Euler's summation formula](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Il64dZELHEIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> $$\sum\limits_{y< n\leq x}f(n)= \int\limits_{y}^{x}f(t)dt + \int\limits_{y}^{x}\{t\}f'(t)dt-\{x\}f(x)+\{y\}f(y) \tag{1}$$

and

> $$\int \frac{\ln{x}}{x^2} dx=-\frac{\ln{x} + 1}{x} + C \tag{2}$$

we have ($n=1$ is trivial, we will consider $n\geq2$)
$$\sum\limits_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}=
\int\limits_{2}^{x}\frac{\ln{t}}{t^2}dt+\int\limits_{2}^{x}\{t\}\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}dt-\{x\}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}=\\
\frac{\ln{2}+1}{2}-\frac{\ln{x}+1}{x}+\int\limits_{2}^{x}\{t\}\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}dt-\{x\}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2} \tag{3}=...$$

---

Now, $\forall x\geq2$
$$\left|\{x\}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}\right|\leq \frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}$$
and (it's worth noting that $2\ln{2}-1>0$)
$$\left|\int\limits_{2}^{x}\{t\}\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}dt\right| \leq \int\limits_{2}^{x}\left|\{t\}\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}\right|dt \leq
\int\limits_{2}^{x}\left|\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}\right|dt=\\
\int\limits_{2}^{x}\frac{2\ln{t}-1}{t^3}dt=-\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}+\frac{\ln{2}}{2^2}$$
this shows that 
$\int\limits_{2}^{\infty}\{t\}\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}dt=I$ exists (by taking $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}$) and
$$\int\limits_{2}^{x}\{t\}\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}dt=I-\int\limits_{x}^{\infty}\{t\}\frac{1-2\ln{t}}{t^3}dt=
I+\int\limits_{x}^{\infty}\{t\}\frac{2\ln{t}-1}{t^3}dt\leq \\
I+\int\limits_{x}^{\infty}\frac{2\ln{t}-1}{t^3}dt=I+\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}$$

---

Continuing from $(3)$
$$...=\frac{\ln{2}+1}{2}+I-\frac{\ln{x}+1}{x}+O\left(\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}\right)=
E-\frac{\ln{x}+1}{x}+O\left(\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}\right) \tag{3a}$$
where $E$ is a constant. From $(3a)$ we see that 
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(\sum\limits_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}\right)=E \tag{4}$$
which simply means
$$\sum\limits_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}=O(1) \tag{5}$$

Also, [Chebyshev's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function) has [the property](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevFunctions.html) that
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\theta(x)}{x}=1 \Rightarrow \theta(x)=O(x) \tag{6}$$

All these together
$$x\left(\sum\limits_{2\leq n\leq x}\frac{\ln{n}}{n^2}\right)+\theta(x)=xO(1)+O(x)=O(x)$$

Comment: cant you just use integral test to prove the convergence and then proceed from there?

Comment: Euler's summation formula, in a way, is a stricter form of integration test. Apostol's "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory" has an entire section dedicated to it (page ~54)

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to analytic number theory and i did consider using the summation formula. But the integral test seemed easier. but just to clarify its not wrong to use the integral test it this case to show that the partial sums are bounded right?

Comment: You could definitely try it, bounding the summation index to $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$, then studying monotonicity of $\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2}$ on $[2,\infty)$, then concluding that $\sum \leq \int ... = const$. It's still a bit of writing :)